# Apply an ellipsis to each line in multiline text if exceeds div width

Tags: html, css

Is there a solution to add an ellipsis on each line inside a div when the line exceeds div width? I've tried using `-webikit-` but doesn't seems to work for this.

I have text in the div tag which loads dynamically. I want to apply a text ellipsis after each line with a maximum number of lines to display are two.

For example, I have this text and `div style='width=110`

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
aliquip
```

and CSS

```
<div Style='width : 110;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
max-height: 2.6em;
line-height: 1.3em;'
>
</div>
```

**Expected display**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
eiusmod tempor incidi...
```

**Current display**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
```

For short text like,

```
Lorem ipsum
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
```

This is what it should look ( no ellipsis )

```
Lorem ipsum
eiusmod tempor incidi...
```

Comment: Are the lines separate or is it one big paragraph?

Comment: It is a paragraph with newline characters in it